# Retrieve the specific date from a table based on current date

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have below specific due dates in my table

```
DueDates
2015-01-30
2014-12-31
2014-11-28
2014-10-31
```

I need a query to retrieve the specific date based on current date.

Ex: If my current date is 11/06 then I should retrieve only 2014-11-28 until my current date is 11/28. If my current date greater than 2014-11-28 than I should retrieve 2014-12-31.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you need the next date closest to your current date? Try this on for size:

```
Select TOP 1 DueDates from Table where DueDates >=GETDATE()
ORDER BY DueDates 
ASC;
```

Comment: Ok. I used below but getting 2014-12-31        Declare @sdate DateTime
set @sdate='2014-11-06'

SELECT TOP(1) dd.date 
     FROM   duedates AS dd 
     where dd.date >=@sdate
     ORDER BY dd.date DESC

Comment: Oops sorry i meant ascending. But still your query should have resulted to 2015-01-30. Try ascending and tell me what happens

Comment: Replicated this in SQL server and it is running fine.

Comment: Wow this works like charm!!!!. Fantastic. You saved my couple of hours. Thanks a lot!!!